# Multiline edittext with text limit

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I create a multiline edittext with text limit?
I set the maxLength of edittext but it made the edittext singleline and if I add inputType to textMultiLine then the imeOptions  set as actionDone won't show. I don't want to set static value for the maxLines attribute.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/activityNameHint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLength="500"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
       />
```

And also when the edittext reaches its limit the keyboard is still allowing the text which makes it difficult to delete the text. How to solve this issue?

Comment: unable to replicate the problem

Answer (score 2):

```
new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

}
```

});

by overriding text change listener, you can specify the max length in ontextchange() and add condition there and do what ever you want